# Return facebook login from CustomTabsIntent authorization back to application

Tags: android, facebook, tabs, authorization

My app open web page for login to the app throw webview.
This page contains additional login throw facebook.
last changes from facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews not allow open facebook login page in one webview.
wherefore i create

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  if (url.contains("facebook")) {

     CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
     CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
     customTabsIntent.intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(url));
     return true;
   }
}
```

but how can i return back to my login page and retrieve facebook authorization?

Authorization works, but it opens my data in new chrome tab but not in my app.

Comment: From what I can understand from the documentation, you will need to use `Facebook's Android SDK`, check this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/

Comment: Yes but sdk seems work by pushing LoginButton, but i have webview and retrieving url from webview.

Comment: Sorry, but no. I think better solution to make login by native android, not via webview